# I Can't Uploading File with fs.createWriteStream and req.pipe

Tags: html, node.js, forms, file-upload, node-modules

I read this tutuorial and tried it:
https://debugmode.net/2014/01/14/how-to-upload-file-in-node-js/

html:

```
<form action="/post-a-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="file" required>
</form>
```

app.js:

```
app.post("/post-a-file",  function (req, res){

    var destinationFile = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/movies");
    req.pipe(destinationFile)
    
   req.on('end', ()=>{ console.log("end") })
})
```

but there is not a file in `/movies`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it this way.  Your post is arriving as `multipart/form-data` and you need middleware to parse that for you.  That middleware will then likely give you an option to put the resulting file data into a file.  See [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for one option for that middleware.  If you're just uploading a single file, you probably want to use the `upload.single()` variation of multer.

Comment: can I make a procces bar with multer? (X% completed...)

Comment: @bahoz99 - It's worth doing a search on that topic.  Here's one of the search results: [Tracking progress of file upload in multer with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288625/tracking-progress-of-file-upload-in-multer-nodejs).  There are other posts on the same topic.